# Number of Spanish-speaking countries?

Tags: hispanoamérica, rae

I once had a PDF *Ortografīa de la Lengua Española* from the Real Academía. It was free, but now they sell it bound for more than I’m willing to pay.  On one of the first few pages, it listed all the Academías that endorsed it.  There were 31, but one was USA.

But when I wanted to contest a claim that there are twenty, everything I could find agrees with twenty (±1).  **Is my memory really that bad, or is there another explanation?**

Comment: No sé a cuál documento te referís. Hay dos ediciones que yo sepa, una de 1999 otra de 2010. Ambas están circulando por la web y las podés encontrar no con mucho esfuerzo. Y en ambos casos conté 21, puede ser que te hayas equivocado.

Comment: Probablemente tienes razón.  Hace muchos años que lo ví.

Answer (score 3):

El español se habla oficialmente en 21 países, que son;

- España, México, Guatemala, El Salvador, Honduras, Nicaragua, Costa Rica, Panamá, Colombia, Ecuador, Perú, Bolivia, Chile, Argentina, Uruguay, Paraguay, Venezuela, Puerto Rico, República Dominicana, Cuba y Guinea Ecuatorial.

Hasta donde yo se y más allá de los países enumerados, se habla español de manera no oficial en EEUU (aunque en algunos estados también es oficial), isla de Guam (EEUU), País Aruba, Antillas Holandesas, Belice, Brasil, Andorra, Gibraltar, en algunas zonas del norte de África como en Marruecos, Argelia o el Sahara y de manera residual aún quedan vestigios en Filipinas.